CSRF Spring Security 6 Login Single Page Application
Using Spring Security 6 with Javascript Single Page Application. Calling the login Url does not push through the login as it always return status 200. I followed the configuration for Spring CSRF https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-javascript-spa
But, it never goes to my api for login/authentication. Below is my sample configuration.
            http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                        .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new SpaCsrfTokenRequestHandler()))
                .addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                    ...
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/api/authentication")
                    .successHandler(new WebLoginHandler());

Javascript:
const response = fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/authentication", {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
            headers: {
                'X-XSRF-TOKEN': getToken()
            }
    
        }).then(res => {
         if (res.ok) {


                //implem here
             }
});

I tried to pass the X-XSRF-TOKEN in the request of my /api/authentication but it never goes to successHandler(), but when I disable the csrf (which is not an option), it works.
The response I am getting is a response with type 'cors'. I have already defined a corsFilter. I have also created a CsrfTokenFilter and I get the token when I load my page to / path. Is there any steps I missed? Because the /api/authentication successhandler was never called with csrf enabled.
